Variance of Estimator in Casella and Berger
Hi I'm trying to read Casella and Berger.
In example 7.3.21 on page 345 they consider the family of distributions Uniform($\theta$, $\theta +1$) and are proposing estimators of theta based on a single observation. They claim that it is easy to see that the estimator $X - \frac12 + \sin(2\pi X) / (2\pi)$ has variance 0.71 (the point being that this is less than the variance of the obvious estimator $X- \frac12$).
However when I do the computation I can't seem to get this.
\begin{align}
Var_\theta(X - \frac12 + \sin(2\pi X) / (2\pi))
&= \int_\theta^{\theta+1} (x - \frac12 + \sin(2\pi x) / (2\pi) -\theta)^2 dx \\
&= (3 + 2 π^2 - 12 \cos(2 π \theta))/(24 π^2) \\
&\approx 0.0959985 - 0.0506606 \cos(2\pi \theta)
\end{align}
Am I missing something very simple? Thanks!

I can't figure it out either. Mathematica agrees with your answer. Quite "straightforward" indeed!

And to be slightly more precise, since the variance of $X-\frac{1}{2}$ is $\frac{1}{12}$, the variance of $\sin(2\pi X)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ and the covariance between $X-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sin(2\pi X)$ is given by C&B to be $-\frac{\cos(2\pi \theta)}{2\pi}$, I don't understand how it would be possible for the variance of a linear combination of these two quantities to be independent of $\theta$.

@JohnMadden Thanks! This was also my confusion.

this does not appear in their errata: https://archived.stat.ufl.edu/casella/class/errata7.pdf

@JohnMadden Yes, I had checked the errata before posting a question.

From the way that passage of the book is set up, it seems they want us to think of the estimator $X-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sin(2\pi X)}{2\pi}$ as a linear combination of the ``naive" estimator $A = X-\frac{1}{2}$ and $B=\sin(2\pi X)$, which has expectation zero (i.e. is an "estimator of zero" in their terminology).
They establish for us that $\mathbb{V}[A] = \frac{1}{12}$ and that the covariance between $A$ and $B$ is $\mathbb{CoV}[A,B] = -\frac{\cos(2\pi\theta)}{2\pi}$. By using the formula $\sin(x)^2 = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$, we can see that $\mathbb{V}[B] = \frac{1}{2}$.
Thus, we can get the desired estimator as $C:= A + \frac{B}{2\pi}$, and using the rule that $\mathbb{V}[a X_1 + b X_2] = a^2\mathbb{V}[X_1] + 2 ab \mathbb{CoV}[X_1,X_2] + b^2 \mathbb{V}[X_2]$, we establish that (just as you did):
$$
\mathbb{V}[C] = \frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{8\pi^2} - \frac{\cos(2\pi\theta)}{2\pi^2}\approx 0.0959985 - 0.0506606 \cos(2\pi\theta)\,.
$$
The lesson we are supposed to take away is that if we have a reasonable estimator ($A$ in our case) that has nonzero correlation with an estimator of zero ($B$ in our case), we should be able to combine them to create an even better estimator.
In this case, we see that the covariance contribution to the variance of $C$ is negative whenever $\cos(2\pi\theta)>0$, or in other words, when $\theta-\lfloor\theta\rfloor\in (0,\frac{1}{4})\cup(\frac{3}{4},1)$.
Furthermore, this is sufficient to overwhelm the additional variance introduced by $\mathbb{V}[B]$ if $\cos(2\pi\theta)>\frac{1}{4}$.
I really don't see how we can avoid a dependence on $\theta$ in the variance of the estimator. But as the commenter Scortchi pointed out, the exercise still achieves the goal of showing that sometimes there just isn't a Uniformly Minimum Variance Unbiased Estimator; which unbiased estimator is best depends on the value of the unknown parameter $\theta$. Indeed, I'll add that in complex likelihoods, this is the typical case; only in nice situations like a Gaussian linear model when observations exceed parameters or some such circumstance should we expect UMVUE to exist, and in a more complicated situation, we should consider ourselves quite lucky if we can find one.
Maybe you'll also just allow me a quick comment on the use of language like "it is easy to show" or, what C&B say in this passage, that it is "straightforward" to show. We see here how it can lead to embarrassment when what you thought was trivially true is in fact incorrect. In general, it can also demotivate students who think they are not even able to show something trival! I hope my generation of writers in stats can reserve such terminology for the situation where if the reader is not able to show such a thing is true, they would be better served going back and reading earlier parts of the text. Even if this example were not flawed, I think the fact that we need the relationship $\sin(x)^2 = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$ is enough to make any turn of phrase like "it is easy to show" inappropriate for a textbook (obviously that would be fine in a research article).

(+1) Despite the error, the example still serves its purpose: an unbiased estimator of $\theta$, $X-\tfrac{1}{2}$, is shown not to be UMVUE by demonstrating its correlation with an unbiased estimator of zero. It's enough that for some values of $\theta$, the also unbiased estimator $X-\tfrac{1}{2} + \tfrac{\sin(2\pi X)}{2\pi}$ has lower variance

@Scortchi-ReinstateMonica also thanks for pointing that out I had misinterpreted the point of the exercise.

Thanks for the detailed answer!
